# Displaying the same image in Python using a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to make this animation of moving ants and need to display multiple ants (same image) to the screen. You can see from below that I am loading the same object twice. I was wondering if there is an easier approach displaying multiple images in different locations on the screen? Is it possible to make a reference or copy to the loaded image "ant" and use it to create multiple images? Maybe a while loop?

```
def run_game_loop(self):

    is_game_over = False

    ant = Ant_Object('Ant2.jpg', 20, 400, 25, 25)
    ant1 = Ant_Object('Ant2.jpg', 60, 400, 25, 25)

    while not is_game_over:

        # to break of the loop we call upon all possible events on the screen
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                is_game_over = True

        # redraw the screen to be a blank white window
        self.game_screen.fill(WHITE_COLOR)
        self.game_screen.blit(self.image, (0,0))

        ant.move(self.width)
        ant.draw(self.game_screen)

        ant1.move(self.width)
        ant1.draw(self.game_screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(self.TICK_RATE)
```

Comment: I think you want to spawn multiple copies of the same sprite similarly to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389487/spawning-multiple-of-the-same-sprite and in this intro guide: http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites